# Multiple YouTube Player API

Tags: javascript, html, css, youtube

All,

I am trying the implementation of buttons that control multiple videos at once.

▼Sample:
https://jsfiddle.net/g3q6ts0k/31/

▼HTML:

```js
//play
var clickElement = document.getElementById("play");
clickElement.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  player.playVideo();
}, false);
//pause
var clickElement = document.getElementById("pause");
clickElement.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  player.pauseVideo();
}, false);
//change
$('#play').click(function() {
  $('#play').css('display', 'none');
  $('#pause').css('display', 'inline-block');
});
$('#pause').click(function() {
  $('#play').css('display', 'inline-block');
  $('#pause').css('display', 'none');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="media">
  <iframe class="player" type="text/html" width="640" height="360" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/M7lc1UVf-VE?enablejsapi=1" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</div>

<div class="media">
  <iframe class="player" type="text/html" width="640" height="360" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ZxnRp4p9SGk?enablejsapi=1" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</div>

<div class="media">
  <iframe class="player" type="text/html" width="640" height="360" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/D-eX-rnvEzI?enablejsapi=1" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</div>

<button id="play">play</button>
<button id="pause">pause</button>
```

Do you know the reason why it does not work properly?

Thanks.